# `no such file or directory` when mirroring with wget

Tags: wget, mirroring

I'm trying to save a local version of the [clojure](http://clojure.org) [docs](http://clojuredocs.org) with the `wget` command:

```
wget --user-agent=firefox --ignore-length -c -km 
"http://clojuredocs.org/quickref/Clojure Core"`
```

but keep getting a `no such file or directory` when it reaches some links like  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rem which obviously exist because you can get there with a browser. I'm guessing this is a problem with the way `wget` is building/concatenating the path. **How do you fix this?**. I've tried other options like `--user-agent` and `--ignore-length` but I keep getting the same results as seen below(you'll have to open the image to see the messages properly).

[image]

This seems to be a problem with mirroring because the command:

```
wget http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rem
```

works okay.

Comment: `http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core` get's saved as a file named `clojure_core`. That's why no folder `clojure_core` can be created. Perhaps you can work around with `-nd` which doesn't create a directory hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. It works when I create the folder `clojure_core` first so that any other file named `clojure_core` will be renamed to clojure_core1 and so on. Question is, why does it do that? I've tried the `-nd` option and it just causes other problems, e.g it gets stuck in a loop trying to download `robots.txt` so many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem originates from the behavior of `wget` to save the URL `http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core` to a file named `./clojuredocs.org/clojure_core`, but the URL `http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/` (notice the trailing slash) to a file named `./clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/index.html`.

Once the *file* `./clojuredocs.org/clojure_core` is created, following downloads of e.g. `http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/something` are doomed to fail, because `wget` can't create a *directory* `./clojuredocs.org/clojure_core` anymore.

This was reported as bug [#29647](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=29647) on the *GNU Wget Bugtracker*.

With the provided [patch](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/download.php?file_id=25677) (which obviously didn't make into the official source code) this problem vanishes and `wget` is forced to create the directory first.  So, the download can continue.

However, `http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core` gets saved as `./clojuredocs.org/clojure_core.1`, not as `./clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/index.html`.

I cannot judge if the link-converter (`-k`) is smart enough to make the links in this mirrored local copy working... I stopped the download after a few minutes. (I'm too impatient `;)`)

Comment: I had no luck with that patch. It introduces undefined methods that break the build. That site has major issues, you knew right canceling the download. It needs a lot of baby sitting and manual intervention. I gave up too after about 20mb. I'm going to have to work with that. Thanks for the answer, I wouldn't have looked in the bugtracker.